# background-attachment: fixed moving backwards on Chrome

Tags: html, css, background-position

I'm experiencing a very strange bug with `background-position: fixed` in Chrome (v67 on macOS) where the background image actually moves up when I scroll, rather than being `fixed`.

Here is a codepen of the issue: https://codepen.io/alexismo/pen/xzwmRE
and here is a gif of it: https://gfycat.com/PolishedHarshAfricangroundhornbill

The content of the page is structured as

```
<body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div class="rest-of-the-site"></div>
</body>
```

```css
.background-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in the latest release of Chrome. This is not the intended behavior. I would recommend filing a bug report if one is not already entered.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a bug, that is how is background-attachment should work. If you want image to stay on screen you should use position:fixed;

Comment: Is that really how it's supposed to work? It doesn't work like that in Firefox or Edge, nor did it work like that in any previous version of Chrome. The background scrolling behaviour of my site changed completely with the latest Chrome update (67.0.3396.62 on Windows).

Comment: i don't perhaps you are correct, but position fixed worked in codepen so i wrote answer. Im not really css expert, but in code pen there was position absolute that is probably why it wouldnt scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Its working in the desired way. For more clarity go through [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Although what you wish to achieve can be done by bit tweaking in your code:

```css
.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('http://alexismorin.com/images/watertown.jpg');
  z-index: -1;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

p {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <div>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
    <p>
      Site is here
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Master.Deep your example has the background image always in view. This is not what I want. I want the background image to eventually be covered by the rest of the content (all the <p>aragraphs) as they are scrolled into view. See the behaviour of `position:fixed` here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-attachment/

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a pseudo element instead. Try this:

```
body:after{
    content: '';
    background-image: url('http://alexismorin.com/images/watertown.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **apply `position: relative` to the body tag**, since it is the ancestor of your background-image div.

Then **set the height of the `.background-image` to `100vh`**. This will make it the height of the window, but it won't always be in view.

```css
/* Since the body element is the parent of the .background-image, we need to set its position to relative */
body {
  position: relative;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* be exactly the height of the viewport, no bigger */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('http://alexismorin.com/images/watertown.jpg');
  z-index: -1;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

p {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p><p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p><p>
    Site is here
  </p><p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
  <p>
    Site is here
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Google Chrome 67. This will fix it, give it a try:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

More at:
https://victorfont.com/workaround-for-chrome-67-parallax-bug/

Comment: Didn't help my issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it involves the fact that there is a "position: absolute" that falls above your "position: fixed" in the hierarchy of CSS rules. Look for the absolute positioning that is causing your issue. For me, I went into the Developer Tools of Chrome and unchecked the boxes which had positions counter to "fixed" until I pinpointed the issue. Mine was in a piece of Javascript code. Hope this can help someone.