# 'background-attachment: fixed' breaks when 'position: absolute' is used on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When using `background-attachment: fixed;` in conjunction with `position: absolute;` the parallax scroll effect is reversed or goes into the wrong direction. The effect works fine when `position: absolute;` is not applied.

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/0xbbadbeef/pen/bKaYQp

```
.attached-abs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://thetypewritermovie.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/shaw2.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This same CSS works on Edge fine but refuses to work on Chrome.

Am I using the property wrong or is there any workaround?

Comment: It looks like a bug in Google Chrome 67. Try solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659755/background-attachment-fixed-moving-backwards-on-chrome/51304839#51304839

Answer (score 0):

you may try to set the position into relative `position:relative;`

Hope it helps

Cheers!

Comment: I'm trying to overlap another div on top of the image, using `position: relative;` would defeat the purpose

Comment: found this it might help you mate. https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/

Comment: I tried playing around with `will-change: transform;` but nothing changed. I'm starting to believe this is a bug with chrome itself.